# Cant activate the PixelYourSite plugin because it triggers a fatal error

Tags: wordpress, plugins

PixelYourSite plugin Version 7.2.1

```
Warning: include(/srv/www/proofskinsolutions.com/releases/20201222150400/web/app/plugins/pixelyoursite/vendor/composer/../techcrunch/wp-async-task/wp-async-task.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/proofskinsolutions.com/releases/20201222150400/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
    
Warning: include(): Failed opening '/srv/www/proofskinsolutions.com/releases/20201222150400/web/app/plugins/pixelyoursite/vendor/composer/../techcrunch/wp-async-task/wp-async-task.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/proofskinsolutions.com/releases/20201222150400/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Async_Task' not found in /srv/www/proofskinsolutions.com/releases/20201222150400/web/app/plugins/pixelyoursite/modules/facebook/facebook-server-async-task.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /srv/www/proofskinsolutions.com/releases/20201222150400/web/app/plugins/pixelyoursite/modules/facebook/facebook-server.php(12): require_once() #1 /srv/www/proofskinsolutions.com/releases/20201222150400/web/app/plugins/pixelyoursite/pixelyoursite.php(43): require_once('/srv/www/proofs...') #2 /srv/www/proofskinsolutions.com/releases/20201222150400/web/app/plugins/pixelyoursite/facebook-pixel-master.php(47): require_once('/srv/www/proofs...') #3 /srv/www/proofskinsolutions.com/releases/20201222150400/web/wp/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(2297): include('/srv/www/proofs...') #4 /srv/www/proofskinsolutions.com/releases/20201222150400/web/wp/wp-admin/plugins.php(191): plugin_sandbox_scrape('pixelyoursite/f...') #5 {main} thrown in /srv/www/proofskinsolutions.com/releases/20201222150400/web/app/plugins/pixelyoursite/modules/facebook/facebook-server-async-task.php on line 8
```